# Wrong shadows in smooth mode

Tags: modeling

I deleted the old right arm and leg, created new and connected them, but now in the smooth mode I have this wrong shadows. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Check the normals by turning on Face Orientation on the Overlays menu then if necessary go into Edit mode, select All, and use Shift-N to recalculate them.

Comment: Works, thank you very much!

Comment: Good! Next time, delete half of the entire model and then add a Mirror modifier! If you then want to edit each side of the model separately apply the modifer.